# Build celadon android source error: : Please resolve Conflict(s) and re-run lunch

Tags: android

I followed celadon guide to build android source for my x86 platform device.

https://01.org/projectceladon/documentation/getting-started/build-source#build-os-image

`$ make clobber`

`$ source build/envsetup.sh`

`$ lunch caas-userdebug`

few minutes later, I got this error:

```
Project vendor/intel/external/project-celadon/audio
    Applying        01_679470_1-Tuning-period_size-and-period_count-for-QEMU-KVM.patch


        ALERT : Conflicts Observed while patch application !!           
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86


        Error: Please resolve Conflict(s) and re-run lunch...
Executing mixin update...
Updater-caas: processing: device/intel/project-celadon/caas/mixins.spec
Updater-caas: mixinsdir: device/intel/mixins/groups
```

I have no idea to resolve this problem, is there someone Who has encountered a similar problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reset my source code by:

```
repo forall -vc "git reset --hard"
```

And it worked.